# When removing a column from a view in snowflake, columns IS_NULLABLE constraint changes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Example of the change:

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW1
AS
SELECT CUSTOMER, ID, FLAG FROM TABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW2
AS
SELECT CUSTOMER,ID FROM TABLE

After removed a column from select statement, I compared 2 views in information_schema.columns. IS_NULLABLE value for 2 columns(E.G CUSTOMER,ID) changes from YES to NO. No luck from google, can anyone explain the reason for this changes please?

Answer (score 0):

can you please describe the steps that you followed, as i tried the following and was not able to reproduce.

```
create or replace  table user_info2(CUSTOMER varchar2(50)  , id varchar2(100) , flag varchar2(10));
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'USER_INFO2';
CREATE OR REPLACE view VIEW1 AS SELECT CUSTOMER, ID, FLAG FROM USER_INFO2;
CREATE OR REPLACE view VIEW1 AS SELECT CUSTOMER,ID FROM USER_INFO2;

select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'VIEW1';
```

Comment: Hi my steps are as follows: TO fully qualify view1 in STG_DB.PRODUCTION.VIEW1,view2 in STG_DB.TESTING.VIEW2. All the rest is copying view1's query to create view2 in STG_DB.TESTING but without one column flag.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_table(customer TEXT, id NUMBER, flag BOOLEAN);

CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT customer, id, flag FROM table_table;

SELECT table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable 
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'VIEW1';
```

looks nice and normal

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | IS_NULLABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VIEW1 | ID | 2 | YES |
| VIEW1 | FLAG | 3 | YES |
| VIEW1 | CUSTOMER | 1 | YES |

make another view:

```
CREATE view VIEW2 AS SELECT CUSTOMER, ID FROM table_table;

SELECT table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable 
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'VIEW2';
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | IS_NULLABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VIEW2 | ID | 2 | YES |
| VIEW2 | CUSTOMER | 1 | YES |

also normal, so lets try recreate the first view, but with one less column

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view VIEW1 AS SELECT customer, id FROM table_table;

SELECT table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable 
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'VIEW1';
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | IS_NULLABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VIEW1 | ID | 2 | YES |
| VIEW1 | CUSTOMER | 1 | YES |

Ok, lets get crazy, let alter the actual table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_table(CUSTOMER text NOT NULL, id number NOT NULL, flag BOOLEAN);

SELECT table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'VIEW1';
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | IS_NULLABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VIEW1 | ID | 2 | YES |
| VIEW1 | CUSTOMER | 1 | YES |

so changing the table, on which the view sits, didn't change the the views details, now lets recreate that view..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE view VIEW1 AS SELECT CUSTOMER, ID FROM table_table;

SELECT table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable 
    FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'VIEW1';
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION | IS_NULLABLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VIEW1 | ID | 2 | NO |
| VIEW1 | CUSTOMER | 1 | NO |

Now we see a change. So that begs the question has the table changed?

Comment: Thanks for the help! To answer your question, the underlying table has not changed. Only other thing I can think of is these two views i compared are in different database/schema, VIEW1 is in production and VIEW2 is in Testing.

Comment: Essentially I just copied view1's script to re-create a DB.TESTING.VIEW2 but delete the flag from select statement. Can't think of a reason where the changes coming from

Comment: Are the table s the same in both environments. Aka the view is_nullable is just a reflection of the table under it

Comment: Yes, source tables are the same.